# Wired connection Issue on Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, networking, upgrade, ethernet

I recently ran sudo apt-get update and upgrade on my Ubuntu 16.04 and after this, my Ubuntu wont go online using the wired connection even though it shows to be connected under Ethernet Network. Also, everything appears to be working fine when connected through wireless network.
Below is my ifconfig output:

```
ifconfig
enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:2a:72:cc:87:48  
      inet addr:192.168.1.39  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::812d:c236:8d77:aed8/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: fd50:680a:d634:e900:2116:97ee:4b93:8596/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:11276 (11.2 KB)  TX bytes:30260 (30.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:133982 (133.9 KB)  TX bytes:133982 (133.9 KB)

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:0e:c4:07:15:df  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7061 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4901 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7589626 (7.5 MB)  TX bytes:661641 (661.6 KB)
```

LSHW:

```
lshw -C network
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlp6s0
   version: 01
   serial: ec:0e:c4:07:15:df
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 07
   serial: b8:2a:72:cc:87:48
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f7800fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

LSPCI:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
     Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 --
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1028:0652]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

LSMOD:

```
lsmod | grep r816*
r8169                  77824  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
```

I followed a couple of threads in this forum, installed r8168-dkms using Synaptic, added

```
auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet dhcp
```

to network/interfaces file and none worked. So, i thought someone here might help resolving this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to resolve this issue by Clicking on Edit Connections-> select Wired connection that your connected to -> press Edit -->IPV4 settings and selecting Method to be Automatic(DHCP). It was Manual Before